# Section symbol \S not rendering sans-serif in cmbright?

Tags: fonts, symbols

Is the section symbol `\S` supported in cmbright? If not, how can I get a sans-serif section symbol? The MWE gives me a serif version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmbright}

\begin{document}
The section character \S\ is not rendering sans-serif.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The § character is taken from the math symbol font, when the output encoding is OT1 (as in your example); the font used is `cmbrs10` which is essentially a copy of `cmsy10`, the math symbol font of Computer Modern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cmbright}

\begin{document}
The section character \S\ is not rendering sans-serif.
\end{document}
```

gives a sans serif version:

[image]

If not then have a look into your log file. There must be a warning if a charcter is not available in a specific font. I used an up-to-date TeXLive 2014